# Delete Action doesn't get called

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On click of delete link i want to call DeleteConfirmed Method in my Student Controller.

Student Controller Code

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
        db.Students.Remove(student);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Index.cshtml has delete link (last line of code) on click of which i want the DeleteConfirmed to be called but the below expects delete.cshtml to be present.I don't want to show delete view and just want the delete to happen asynhronously.

```
@model IEnumerable<SMS.Model.Student>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Student";
}


<h2>Student</h2>
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegistrationNo)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MiddleName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateofBirth)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegistrationNo)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MiddleName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateofBirth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id },new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post"})

    </td>
</tr>
```

}

}

Answer (score 1):

Inside the view instead of

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

You should have

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteConfirmed", "YourControllerName"))
```

If won't work, removing `ActionName("Delete")` should do the trick.

Let me know if that was of help.

Comment: no..it doesn't work. Still it calls get on Delete instead of post,gives error                                                         The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Student/Delete/5

Comment: Try replacing `@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id },new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post"})` with `@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteConfirmed", new { id = item.Id },new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post"})` with and without ActionName("Delete")` above the action.

Comment: Was it of any help for you please? Thanks.